# Can someone help identify this set from 2011 (Star Wars?)

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I got this set but without instructions and as I have no idea what it my son can’t build it. Bags says 2011 and 135149.

Here’s a picture of the bags.

[image]

Comment: New here not sure how to add more pics

Comment: The year on the bags concerns the copyright on the bags, and have no relation to the set.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 6):

At the minimum, two separate sets:

[*Set #75048 The Phantom...*](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75048-1)
[image]

Only set to have a windshield in this style.

[image]

Astromech's body and leg found in pieces.

[image]
[image][image]

*[... and Set #75050-1 B-Wing.](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75050-1)*
[image]

Need less reflective/obstructed pics to identify more potential sets.

**How to adds pics.**

(Sorry rushing to go to work).

1. Edit your post.

   - [image]

     2. Position cursor where you want to drop image.
   - [image]

     3. Hit "picture frame icon" then browse to your image to add it.
   - [image]

     4. Save edited post by hitting blue "Save Edits" button.
   - [image]

Comment: There are bags numbered 2,3 and 5 in the picture. That would exclude the Phantom as it only has limited pieces. The B-wing does not have any (visible) yellow pieces, so unless those are internally, that wouldn’t be a match either.

Comment: Calling for a mediator!  Where's Alexander "Hawk-eyes" O'Mara when we need him?

Comment: Deleted my alternative answer after looking closer at the cockpit canopy piece. Phantom indeed, so there is indeed more than 1 set in these bags.

Comment: Non apology accepted, but there are still pieces unaccounted for.  Bag 3 has a bunch o' black or dark brown technic pieces that needs id'ing.  It's too crazy for my eyes to parse these out.

Comment: Wow thank you all so much for responding. I will take additional photos tomorrow to try and better determine what we have but it’s very hopeful that you all were able to help so far with any of it! My son will be so happy!

Comment: How do I add photos in the comments? Can’t seem to figure that out

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. Can't post a picture in comments.  You may post a link to one though, but it would also work if you just edited your original post, so everyone can see the images right off the bat, instead of a character stringed hyperlink. Oh, and welcome to   Bricks.SE! 